# Reading Classes found in a Jar packaged in a Zipfile

Tags: java, reflection, urlclassloader

I’ve spent a lot of time working on an assignment, “read a classfile found in a Jar stored contained in a Zipfile” and always return to the same `ClassNotFoundException`. I’m just seeking some guidance regarding how to proceed. I read many useful links on various sites, but continue to encounter problems either because a daunting task or I lack the knowledge.

Basically, my code successfully reads reads the Zipfile, creates a `JarInputstream` and finds my requested classfile.  My problem, locating the file when the code executes the line, `cl.loadClass(className)` throwing the `ClassNotFoundException`.

```
URL jarUrl = new URL("jar:file:/E:/temp/ZipTest/JarTest_08262014/JarTest3.zip!/activation.jar!/com/sun/activation/viewers/ImageViewer.class"); 
URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {jarUrl });
className= "com/sun/activation/viewers/ImageViewer.class";
Class loadedClass = cl.loadClass(className);
```

Once I've loaded the class I can use the reflection methods to read the classfile. I wrote a class which works when reading jar files located in a directory.

I looked at OpenJDK javap code, but I don’t see any reflection calls. So, I’m lost at this point. Did I construct an incorrect URL?

Any suggestions?

Comment: As far as I know, `URLClassLoader` simply can’t do that. You can process nested `JarInputstream`s in your code but the `URLClassLoader` implementation relies on `JarFile` which does not support nesting…

Comment: the class name you try to load should be the fully qualified class name i.e.`com.sun.activation.viewers.ImageViewer` instead of your `className`-value. Furthermore, it can be necessary to provide the application-classloader in the `newInstance(URL[], ClassLoader)`-method else certain classes not loaded by this classloader might throw exceptions as their byte-definitons are unknown to this classloader

Comment: You probably want to extract the .jar file from the .zip and write it to a temporary file, then create a URLClassLoader consisting of that temporary file's URL.  I'm pretty sure URLClassLoader URLs cannot be individual class files;  each URL must be a .jar file or a directory.

Comment: Thanks guys, gives me something to think about and I try. I'll keep the thread updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the URLClassloader wrong.
Try to use a URL which points only to the JAR file.
Nested Jars are not allowed by default URLClassloader.

Further:
Don't specify the class's *file*.

Means:

`className= "com/sun/activation/viewers/ImageViewer.class";`

should be:

`className= "com.sun.activation.viewers.ImageViewer";`